# Get a total loop count for a loop INSIDE another loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to create a list of unique names and grid locations for some terms found on a website. Although my code might look a bit complicated, I think what I am trying to achieve is fairly simple.

I have created an enumerate for loop inside another enumerate for loop and where I have the stars in my code I would like to enter something that would reflect the total number of loops that the program executes.

So if my first list called "watch_link_urls" is 4 items long, and the second list called "watch_model_description" is 7 items long, I should have a total of 28 loops. What do I put into the brackets containing the stars so that variables "watch_model_description" and "watch_model_description_grid" would read "category_1 =" ... , "category_2 ="..., etc. all the way up to "category_28"?

```
watch_model_description_list = [] 
watch_model_description_grid_list = [] for num, url in enumerate(watch_link_urls):
    dennisov_model_html = urlopen(url).read()
    watch_model_description = findall("dib_02'\>([A-Z \/0-9]+)\<", dennisov_model_html)
    for number, category in enumerate(watch_model_description):
        watch_model_description = 'category_' + str(**********) + ' = Label(window, text = "'+ category +'")'
        watch_model_description_grid = 'category_' + str(**********) + '.grid(padx = 5, pady = 0, row = ' + str(number+3) + ', column = '+ str(num) +')'
```

EDIT: Included entire code below to help with debugging

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, Canvas, END, Spinbox, PhotoImage, Label
from ttk import Progressbar, Combobox
from urllib import urlopen
from re import findall
import re
import itertools
import urllib

## Create a window
window = Tk()

## Give the window a title
window.title('Watch finder')

## Show Dennisov image logo
dennisov_logo_url = "http://i.imgur.com/KD6AK08.gif"
handle = urlopen(dennisov_logo_url)
data = handle.read()
raw_image = PhotoImage(master = window, data = data)
Label(window, image = raw_image, width = 600).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 10)
handle.close

## Types of Dennisov watches
dennisov_type_list = ['Barracuda Limited','Barracuda Chronograph',
                      'Barracuda Mechanical','Speedster','Free Rider',
                      'Nau Automatic','Lady Flower','Enigma','Number One']

dennisov_file = open('dennisov_url.html', 'w')

dennisov_file.write('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Watches</title>
    </head>
    <body>
''')

#### Display the quanity of watches available for each type
##quantity_box = len(watch_option)
##
#### 
##for watch, number in enumerate(watch_option):
##    watch_number_name = watch_option[number][0]
##    watch_number_image = watch_option[number][1]
##    watch_number_price = watch_option[number][2]
##    watch_number_link = watch_option[(number)][3]
####    dennisov_file.write('<h1>' + watch_number_name + '</h1>')
##    print watch_number_image
####    dennisov_file.write('<img src="' + watch_number_image + '">\n')
##    print watch_number_price
####    dennisov_file.write('<h2>' + watch_number_price + '</h2>')
##    print watch_number_link
####    dennisov_file.write('<a href="'+watch_number_link+'">'+watch_number_link+'</a>')
##       

dennisov_file.write('''
</body>
</html>
''')

## Define function for button push
def display_choice():

    dennisov_type_selection = (dennisov_dropdown_box.get())
    if dennisov_type_selection == 'Barracuda Limited':
        dennisov_type = 'barracuda_limited'
    elif dennisov_type_selection == 'Barracuda Chronograph':
        dennisov_type = 'barracuda_chronograph'
    elif dennisov_type_selection == 'Barracuda Mechanical':
        dennisov_type = 'barracuda_mechanical'
    elif dennisov_type_selection == 'Speedster':
        dennisov_type = 'speedster'
    elif dennisov_type_selection == 'Free Rider':
        dennisov_type = 'free_rider'
    elif dennisov_type_selection == 'Nau Automatic':
        dennisov_type = 'nau_automatic'
    elif dennisov_type_selection == 'Lady Flower':
        dennisov_type = 'lady_flower'
    elif dennisov_type_selection == 'Enigma':
        dennisov_type = 'enigma'
    elif dennisov_type_selection == 'Number One':
        dennisov_type = 'number_one'

    dennisov_url = 'https://denissov.ru/en/'+ dennisov_type + '/'
    dennisov_url_subpage = dennisov_url[19:]
##    dennisov_url_subpage_subpage = dennisov_url_subpage[

    ## Make the html document just created equal to an opened and read URL????
    ##???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
    dennisov_html = urlopen(dennisov_url).read()
    ## Replace instances of double quotation marks in the text with singles 
    ## so that the findall regex code does not get confused 
    dennisov_html = dennisov_html.replace('"', "'")

    ## Find all of the images of the watches. Each watch image starts with the text
    ## "img src=". Do not match those with any " symbols in the URL
    watch_image_urls = findall("<img src='(/files/collections/o[^']*)'", dennisov_html)
    ## Add the URL domain to each watch image subpage to create full addresses
    watch_image_urls = ['https://denissov.ru' + remainder for remainder in watch_image_urls]
    ##    dennisov_file.write('        <img src="' + image + '">\n')
    ## Download and save the PNG images to the directory as GIFs so that
    ## Tkinter can use them

    ## Return the watch type. The watch type is in a title tag called "titlusref"
    ## and can be any combination of letters and spaces, followed by a space and
    ## "<" symbol. 
    watch_type = findall("titlusref'\>([a-zA-Z]+ *[a-zA-Z]*) *\<", dennisov_html)[0]

    ## Find all of the links when each watch is clicked. Each watch link starts
    ## with the text "a href=" followed by the subpage, followed by any
    ## letter, number and "_" symbol combination, followed by a backslash
    watch_link_urls = findall("a href='" + (dennisov_url_subpage) + "([A-Za-z0-9_]+/)", dennisov_html)  
    ## Add the main URL to each watch subpage
    watch_link_urls = [str(dennisov_url) + remainder for remainder in watch_link_urls]


    ## Find all of the model numbers of each watch. Each model starts with the text
    ## "covername" then any combination of letters, dots and spaces. 
    watch_models = findall("covername'>([A-Z a-z0-9\.]+)", dennisov_html)
    ## Add the watch type to each watch model, seperated by a space, to create the
    ## full watch names
    watch_names = [str(watch_type) + " " + remainder for remainder in watch_models]

    ## Get current USD to AUD exchange rate using a known currency website
    currency_converter_url = 'http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?From=USD&To=AUD'
    currency_html = urlopen(currency_converter_url).read()
    ## Replace instances of double quotation marks in the text with singles 
    ## so that the findall regex code does not get confused 
    currency_html = currency_html.replace('"', "'")
    ## Find the exchange rate. The exchange rate starts with "uccResultAmount'>"
    ## and is then followed by any combination of numbers with a decimal place
    exchange_rate = float(findall("uccResultAmount'\>([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)", currency_html)[0])

    ## Find the price of the models and make into floats. Each model price contains
    ## numbers followed by the text "USD"
    USD_watch_prices = [float(price) for price in (findall("([0-9]*) usd", dennisov_html))]
    ## Convert the USD watch prices to current AUD prices and round to 2 decimals
    watch_prices = [round(exchange_rate*price, 2) for price in USD_watch_prices]
    ## Add the currency to the prices
    watch_prices = ["AU $" + str(price) for price in watch_prices]

    ## Match each watch name to its image and URL inside a tuple and place each
    ## tuple inside a list
    watch_list = zip(watch_names, watch_image_urls, watch_prices, watch_link_urls)
    ## For each watch tuple (matching image, name and URL), assign a watch number
    watch_option = {'watch_{}'.format(i): e for i, e in enumerate(watch_list)}

## CREATE A LIST OF MODEL DESCRIPTIONS ACCORDING TO THE TYPE OF WATCH SELECTED:
## > Read each model HTML link in watch_link_urls.
## > Search for the terms starting with dib_02 followed by any combination of capital
##  letters, numbers and backslashes.
## > Insert Tkinter instructions to each result as strings
## > Append the results to a list called watch_model_description_list.
    watch_model_description_list = []
    watch_model_description_grid_list = []
    for num, url in enumerate(watch_link_urls):
        dennisov_model_html = urlopen(url).read()
        dennisov_model_html = dennisov_model_html.replace('"', "'")
        watch_model_description = findall("dib_02'\>([A-Z \/0-9]+)\<", dennisov_model_html)
        for number, category in enumerate(watch_model_description):


            watch_model_description = 'category_' + str(loop_count) + ' = Label(window, text = "'+ category +'")'
            watch_model_description_grid = 'category_' + str(loop_count) + '.grid(padx = 5, pady = 0, row = ' + str(number+3) + ', column = '+ str(num) +')'
            watch_model_description_list.append(watch_model_description)
            watch_model_description_grid_list.append(watch_model_description_grid)
            loop_count += 1
    model_option = {'model_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(watch_model_description_list)}
    model_grid_option = {'model_grid{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(watch_model_description_grid_list)}
    model_grid_option_string = '\n'.join(model_grid_option.values())
    model_option_string = '\n'.join(model_option.values())
    print watch_model_description_list
    print watch_model_description_grid_list
    print model_option_string
    print model_grid_option_string

##    models_option = {'model_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(watch_model_description_list)}
##    models_option_string = '\n'.join(models_option.values())
##    print models_option_string

##watch_model_description_list.append(watch_model_description)        


 ## Create a description for each watch model

##    models_list = []
##    models_grid_list = []
##    for number, category in enumerate(watch_model_description_list):
##        models_grid = 'model_' + str(category) + '.grid(padx = 0, pady = 0, row = ' + str(category) + ', column = '+ str(number) +')'
##        models_list.append(models)
##        models_grid_list.append(models_grid)
##        models_option = {'model_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(models_list)}
##    models_option_string = '\n'.join(models_option.values())
##    models_grid_option = {'model_grid_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(models_grid_list)}
##    models_grid_option_string = '\n'.join(models_grid_option.values())
##    exec(models_option_string)
##    exec(models_grid_option_string)
##    print models_option_string
##    print models_grid_option_string

## Create a spinbox 
    spinbox_list = []
    spinbox_grid_list = []
    for number, watch in enumerate(watch_names):
        spinbox = 'spinbox_' + str(number) + ' = Spinbox(window, width = 3, from_=0, to=10)'
        spinbox_grid = 'spinbox_' + str(number) + '.grid(padx = 0, pady = 0, row = 9, column = '+ str(number) +')'
        spinbox_list.append(spinbox)
        spinbox_grid_list.append(spinbox_grid)
        spinbox_option = {'spinbox_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(spinbox_list)}
    spinbox_option_string = '\n'.join(spinbox_option.values())
    spinbox_grid_option = {'spinbox_grid_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(spinbox_grid_list)}
    spinbox_grid_option_string = '\n'.join(spinbox_grid_option.values())
    exec(spinbox_option_string)
    exec(spinbox_grid_option_string)

    prices_list = []
    prices_grid_list = []
    for number, watch in enumerate(watch_prices):
        prices = 'price_' + str(number) + ' = Label(window, text = "'+ watch +'")'
        prices_grid = 'price_' + str(number) + '.grid(padx = 5, pady = 0, row = 8, column = '+ str(number) +')'
        prices_list.append(prices)
        prices_grid_list.append(prices_grid)
        prices_option = {'price_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(prices_list)}
        prices_option_string = '\n'.join(prices_option.values())
    prices_grid_option = {'price_grid_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(prices_grid_list)}
    prices_grid_option_string = '\n'.join(prices_grid_option.values())
    exec(prices_option_string)
    exec(prices_grid_option_string)

    names_list = []
    names_grid_list = []
    for number, watch in enumerate(watch_names):
        names = 'name_' + str(number) + ' = Label(window, text = "'+ watch +'")'
        names_grid = 'name_' + str(number) + '.grid(padx = 5, pady = 0, row = 10, column = '+ str(number) +')'
        names_list.append(names)
        names_grid_list.append(names_grid)
        names_option = {'name_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(names_list)}
    print names_list
    names_option_string = '\n'.join(names_option.values())
    names_grid_option = {'name_grid_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(names_grid_list)}
    names_grid_option_string = '\n'.join(names_grid_option.values())
    exec(names_option_string)
    exec(names_grid_option_string)



##    dennisov_model_selection = Canvas(window, width = 400, height = 850,
##                                  bg = 'white')
##    dennisov_model_selection.grid(padx = 2, pady = 2, row = 1,
##                              column = 0, rowspan = 15, columnspan = 3)




## Create dropdown box text
dennisov_dropdown_text = Label(window, text = "Watch type:", bg = 'White', width = 20)

## Create the dropdown box for the Dennisov watch types
dennisov_dropdown_box = Combobox(window, width = 25,
                                  values = dennisov_type_list)

## Create Dennisov type selection button
dennisov_select_button = Button(window, text = 'Select', command = display_choice, width = 20)

## Locate elements on grid
dennisov_dropdown_text.grid(pady = 2, padx = 2, row = 1, columnspan = 9, sticky = 'W')
dennisov_dropdown_box.grid(pady = 2, padx = 2, row = 1, columnspan = 9, sticky = 'N')
dennisov_select_button.grid(pady = 2, padx = 2, row = 1, columnspan = 9, sticky = 'E')




dennisov_file.close()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a counter variable:

```
loop_count = 1
watch_model_description_list = [] 
watch_model_description_grid_list = [] for num, url in enumerate(watch_link_urls):
    dennisov_model_html = urlopen(url).read()
    watch_model_description = findall("dib_02'\>([A-Z \/0-9]+)\<", dennisov_model_html)
    for number, category in enumerate(watch_model_description):
        watch_model_description = 'category_' + str(loop_count) + ' = Label(window, text = "'+ category +'")'
        watch_model_description_grid = 'category_' + str(loop_count) + '.grid(padx = 5, pady = 0, row = ' + str(number+3) + ', column = '+ str(num) +')'
        loop_count += 1
```

`loop_count` will increase by 1 every time you iterate through your second `for` loop

Comment: Loop count should be in the inner for-loop scope.

Comment: @schillingt Fixed :)

Comment: For some reason many features like the += don't work with my Python. I run 2.7 and am getting the error "loop_count += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'loop_count' referenced before assignment"

Comment: @user88720 Hmm, I'm running it in both python 3 and 2.7 and it works fine. Is your code within a function? If so, try declaring `loop_count` as a global variable

Comment: Maybe you could see what is wrong in my code. I have made an edit with my entire code

Comment: @user88720 - you didn't initialize `loop_count` outside of the loop, like TheGirrafish did on the first line in his example.

Comment: Maybe a nitpick, @TheGirrafish: shouldn't it be `loop_count = 0`?

Comment: @boardrider Depends on your needs, from the OP's code, it looks like he wants the category count to start from 1.